# Highcharts.stockChart Range Selector (zoom) Button Position After the Chart Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to place the range selector button after the chart display area. Any one suggest me how to implement that.

[**Current Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd1Xh.png)

[**Expected Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFkDL.png)

**Code Used**

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chartcontainer', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
            color: '#00c800',
            upColor: '#c80000'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: data,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: [
                [
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one way to do it is to juggle several margins and x/y-positions. The problem is that the positioning for both the navigator and the range selector do not offer very dynamic positioning options.

See this example ([JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5nxnweL1/) based on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/)):

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 20, // Close the gap where the range selector used to be
    marginBottom: 60, // Make space for the new range selector position
},

rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1,
    buttonPosition: {
        x: 0,
        y: 370 // Move the range selector down the Y-axis
    }
},

navigator: {
    top: 300 // Reposition the navigator based on the top of the chart
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post its very helpfull for me :)